# Objective-C protocol as parameter in another protocol

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-protocol

I am trying to create a generic repository (pattern) that accesses my web api. I am having trouble understanding how protocols work in objective-c (I come from c# where interfaces are a bit different).

What I am trying to do is have ProtocolA be a parameter in another ProtocolB and then in the implementation of ProtocolB access methods on ProtocolA, since the object passed in to ProtocolB must implement ProtocolA itself. Am I thinking about that correctly?

This is what I have thus far, but can't seem to get it to work - maybe my logic is wrong:

```
//PGenericModel.h
@protocol PGenericModel <NSObject>
- (void)testMethod;
@end
```

```
//PGenericRepository.h
#import "PGenericModel.h"
@protocol PGenericRepository <NSObject>
@required
- (void)Get:(id<PGenericModel>*)entity;
@end
```

```
//GenericRepository.m
#import "GenericRepository.h"
@implementation GenericRepository
- (void)Get:(id<PGenericModel>*)entity
{
    //GET
    [entity testMethod] <-- this doesn't work...
}
@end
```

Comment: Even if you are coming from C#, please don't use C# naming conventions in Obj-C. For example, all method names should start with a lower case letter and describe their parameters, e.g. `getForEntity:`

Answer (score 7):

It is not working because an `id` type is already a pointer to an Objective-c object.

So you should declare the signature as

```
- (void)Get:(id<PGenericModel>)entity
```

not `id<PGenericModel>*`, otherwise the argument would be a pointer to a pointer to an Objective-C object, you can't send messages to it unless you get the concrete value.